# Error:(54) Error parsing XML: mismatched tag

Tags: android, xml

I'm pretty new at working with Android Studio and I'm trying to "build" the project which gets me the error above.

As I understand, the error means that I didn't close an XML Tag in my .xml file, but I can't find which tag. I've come to the conclusion that maybe the mistake is another that just leads to "mismatched tag".

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.alexa.andorfightapp.SelectEnemy">
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="368dp"
            android:layout_height="495dp">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/auswahlTextBox"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:text="@string/gegenerauswahl" />
            </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="100px"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">


                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/goreBtn"
                    android:layout_height="220px"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:src="@drawable/gore" />

                <ImageButton android:layout_height="220px" android:layout_column="1" android:id="@+id/skralBtn" android:src="@drawable/skral"/>
                <ImageButton android:layout_height="220px" android:layout_column="2" android:id="@+id/trollBtn" android:src="@drawable/troll"/>

            </TableRow>
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="368dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">
            <ImageButton android:layout_height="150dp" android:id="@+id/dragonBtn" android:src="@drawable/dragon_middle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />
        </TableRow>
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">
            <ImageButton android:layout_height="300px" android:id="@+id/specialBtn" android:src="@drawable/star_small" />
            <TableRow/>
        </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: `android.support.constraint.` you need to specify a class after the dot

Comment: replace `android.support.constraint.` with `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout`

Comment: this was just a copy paste error, but thank you

Comment: you are missing 1 `</TableRow>` in the last part of the XML

Comment: please check following layout ..change as per your design.

Comment: @MatPag you are right. One </TableRow> was missing, but android studio still shows the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your last `<TableRow/>` with `</TableRow></TableRow>`

`<TableRow/>` is a self closing node `</TableRow>` is the closing tag for a node, a subtle difference but an important one none the less.

There are many tools which might help you with this kind of issue, I recommend that you  use the XML tools plugin, it will really help you identify these kind of issues. You can use it to check for well formed XML as well as XSD/DTD validation, in addition to it's many formatting tools. But seriously most XML editors will do the job.

Comment: Thank you, I'll change my code and install nodepad++